Should I be worried about this giant crack?
I live in an old apartment that was built in the 1900s. In the last 2 years, this crack has appeared and grown every month. It had been patched 2 years ago as well.
I am worried about the structural integrity. The crack is visible from outside of the building.
Should I be concerned?

Fingers for reference for size of hole in wall/ crack running up wall of apartment

Do you rent or own the place?

A growing crack is always a cause of concern.  If right though the wall, inside to outside, it might be time to listen to Monty Python and run away.  More pictures of the wall further away and from outside will help.

What does "1900s" mean? 1900-1909 or 1900-1999?

Walls don't magically shrink and cause finger-sized gaps. You are experiencing a structural problem. It could be an issue with the foundation or the wood framing behind your walls is rotting and causing some serious issues.

Do you own or rent?

@pipe Usually "1900's" refers to the decade but your confusion is understandable.

That's not a crack. It's a chasm.

What story (level) is your apartment on? Is the crack near an exterior wall possibly on the front or rear of the building? The facade could be pulling away from the rest of the building and could literally collapse at any moment. Example

Yes, you should be concerned, IMO.
Some movement in a house of that age is normal, but a crack of that size (especially considering that it's been repaired once already!) suggests that you have some subsidence going on, somewhere.
I would seek the advice of a surveyor / structural engineer sooner rather than later, as remedial works to your foundations will almost certainly be required.

Since the owner seems to know about this crack, having repaired it previously, the OP should consider reporting it to their city building inspector. The owner apparently isn't doing the appropriate repairs or even acknowledging the severity of the situation, so it seems appropriate to bring in the proper authorities to force the owner to make proper repairs. Leaving cracks like this can lead to infestations or, worst case, the building collapses.

Concur - OP should be looking for other accommodation.

Short Answer: Yes, you should be worried.
Long Answer:
As advice from civil structural engineer, if the crack is horizontal or diagonal you should be less worried, but if the crack is vertical you should be worried as it represent structure integrity issue.

shortest answer: "run!" (Doctor Who's first word to Rose)
